# Funcion de click por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Hola quería saber como puedo pasar esta función  de jquery a javascript pero en vez de tener la función mousedown sea de mouse click

```js
$(".myButton").on("mousedown mouseup", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("active", e.type === "mousedown");
});
```

```css
.myButton {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    boborder-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.myButton.active {
    background-color: #f00;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.95);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.95);
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myButton">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <h3>Some more text</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El equivalente sin jQuery sería algo así:

```js
let buttons= document.querySelectorAll('.myButton');
buttons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.myButton {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    boborder-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.myButton.active {
    background-color: #f00;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.95);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.95);
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="myButton">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <h3>Some more text</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente Pablo eso queria, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar queryselector para obtener la referencia del botón

```
var myButton = document.querySelector(".myButton");
```

Y agregar un listener para el evento click

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  myButton.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Comment: Es correcto, asumi que solo habría un botón

Comment: Sigues usando jQuery, aparte eso no compila

Comment: Gracias Joel y Pablo, creo que me exprese mal yo con la pregunta, lo que necesito seria que funcione como un boton con un titulo y una flecha al costado y que esa flecha se muestre para abajo y clickear haga para arriba, se comprende?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//buscamos el boton
var myButton = document.querySelector(".myButton");
//Si el boton existe y no está nulo
if(myButton != undefined && myButton != null)
{
  //Aquí se agrega el evento del click
  myButton.onclick = function (){
    //guardarmos el contenido del class en la variable clase
    var clase = this.className;
    //Buscamos si el boton NO tiene la clase active
    if(clase.search("active") == -1)
    {
      //Como NO la tiene, entonces agregamos la clase
      this.className += " active ";
    }
    else
    {
      //Si tiene la clase, entonces remplazamos la case con un vacio
      this.className = clase.replace("active", " ");
    }
    
  }
}
```

```css
.myButton {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.myButton.active {
    background-color: #f00;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.95);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.95);
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="myButton">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <h3>Some more text</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias alfonso, creo que me exprese mal yo con la pregunta, lo que necesito seria que funcione como un boton con un titulo y una flecha al costado y que esa flecha se muestre para abajo y clickear haga para arriba, se comprende?